# How to extract image from notes richtextitem?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to copy an image from one notes document to another document in another notes database. The images is supposed to be in a RichText element. I can see the image but the line

```
       Set CRMPhoto = rtnav.GetFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_FILEATTACHMENT)
```

does not populate CRMPhoto. That is, CRMPhoto Is Nothing. Please help!!!

```
    Dim rtnav As NotesRichTextNavigator
    Dim rti As NotesRichTextItem
    Dim  CRMPhoto As Variant

    Set rti = doccrm.GetFirstItem("Seller_Photo")
    'Set rti = doccrm.Seller_Photo(0)

    Set rtnav = rti.CreateNavigator
    Set CRMPhoto = rtnav.GetFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_FILEATTACHMENT)

    If CRMPhoto  Is Nothing Then
        Messagebox "Document contains no image"
        Exit Function
    End If

    While Not(CRMPhoto Is Nothing)

        Set CRMPhoto = rtnav.GetNextElement
    Wend
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving inline images from Lotus notes using lotusscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008237/retrieving-inline-images-from-lotus-notes-using-lotusscript)

Comment: This is not an attachment, but an embedded image. This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008237/retrieving-inline-images-from-lotus-notes-using-lotusscript)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response for I got busy somewhere else.

Anyways here's the piece of code I created assuming the richtextitem has embedded the image(s):


  Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
  Set rtitem = doccrm.GetFirstItem("Seller_Photo")
  
  Forall eo In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects         
   Call eo.ExtractFile( Curdir()  + eo.source )          
  End Forall 


It says Type Mismatch on this line:

Forall eo In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects